# How to authenticate the database by using the Windows service user on Wildfly 9?

Tags: wildfly

I am configuring a data source to use windows authentication that is configuring the Wildfly service.

I put in the connection URL the "integratedSecurity = true" parameter:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/DBEASYFINANCE2_D0000" pool-name="java:/DBEASYFINANCE2_D0000" enabled="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SRVXX:1433;databaseName=DB_XXX;integratedSecurity=true</connection-url>
                    <driver>jtds</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>0</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                    </pool>
                    <validation>
                        <check-valid-connection-sql>select ''</check-valid-connection-sql>
                        <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                    </validation>
                    <timeout>
                        <blocking-timeout-millis>30000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
                        <use-try-lock>60</use-try-lock>
                    </timeout>
                </datasource>
```

When I run the connection test on the DataSource the error occurs:

```
Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
        ("data-source" => "java:/DBEASYFINANCE2_D0000")
    ],
    "operation" => "test-connection-in-pool"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0047: Connection is not valid",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

I'm using Wildfly 9.

Can you tell me what is wrong with my configuration ?